# Nginx config SPA

Tags: node.js, nginx, single-page-application

I need some help with nginx config for SPA. I made mine from pieces I managed to google, but I don't understand how it works.

What I need:

1) Serve static files

```
location ~ \.(css|js|svg|woff|woff2|ico|ttf|eot|jpe?g|png|txt)$ {          
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  expires 1y;
  add_header Cache-Control "public"; 
}
```

If the file is not found I return 404. That's ok if I just type incorrect file name in URL, but if I type incorrect file name in my index.html instead of 404 page I get a blank page. Is that supposed to be this way?

2) Requests to /api need to be redirected to Node backend

```
location /api {
  try_files '' @proxy;
}

location @proxy  {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

I'm not really sure in this line, if it's supposed to look this way

```
try_files '' @proxy;
```

3) And the biggest problem, requests that do not match anything need to return index.html

```
location / {
  try_files '' /index.html;
  expires -1;
}

location = /index.html {
  expires -1;
}
```

As far as I understand first block redirects all unknown requests to index.html, but I don't understand how the second block serves this index.html. I do not write to serve this file, there is no try_files directive.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Serve static files

Your solution is perfectly fine. It is only needed if you require to set different cache control and expiry headers for these URIs. The `try_files` statement is unnecessary as that's the same as the default behaviour.

> 2) Requests to /api need to be redirected to Node backend

Your solution can be simplified to:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}
```

This will process any URI that begins with `/api` **unless** it matches the regular expression in step (1). You can avoid that by using the `^~` operator. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

> 3) And the biggest problem, requests that do not match anything need to return index.html

This is usually implemented as:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    ...
}
```

Unless the request matches any other `location`, or a file, or directory, the URI will be internally rewritten to `/index.html`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: 1) static files, what if static file is not found and I want to redirect to my app's 404 page?    2) request to api I need in several places, so I would like to address it by variable instead of copying the same block multiple times. Do I do it the right way now?     3) For index.html I don't quite understand why I need to search by $uri in files, if I know that I need index.html and not something else on this route?

Comment: If you want a custom 404 handler, you could use `error_page` or `try_files`. Use `include` statements or a regular expression to avoid code repetition. If you really want everything else to go to `index.html` use `try_files /index.html =404;` (the 404 is never reached).